# Wordpress child theme issue

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using a self made child theme for my Wordpress theme. Because I've so much files I've added some folders to my child theme and changed the path in the functions.php to make it a little bit clearer:

[image]

---

My folder structure:

[image]

Now I have the problem that Wordpress having issues loading my files:

```
(index):53 GET http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/themes/Divicss/style.css?ver=4.9.8 net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
```

It loooks like that Wordpress is searching in the original theme but this is wrong. How can I fix this? Or is this even possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`get_template_directory_uri` returns the path to parent theme. You have to use `get_stylesheet_directory_uri`. Also, keep in mind it doesn't append slashes at the end, so you have to do it yourself.

```
wp_enqueue_style('main_css', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/css/style.css');
```

According to the [developer documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/#2-create-a-stylesheet-style-css) `style.css` is a required file, so maybe you can't move that particular file after all, or at least need a dummy one with the child's stanza.

Comment: I'll try this later. I hope this works within a child theme

Comment: Same issue with setting it to this

Comment: @Johnny97 Are you having the issue with all your files ? Updated answer with a link.

Comment: According to Wordpress, the child theme main css can't be moved in to an other folder.